# Connect MySQL distant to codename one

Tags: mysql, web-services, codenameone

i saw in the forum and on the web it's possible to connect mysql with webserver, but i like to juste connect codename one juste with standard MySQL connector, it's possible ?

MySQL it's on distant server and my provider can't make to me a connector webservice

Thank you very mush for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is some information here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html. You will be using the cn1lib CN1Xataface.
There is no standard MySql connector for Codename One that I'm aware of.

Comment: yes thanks, i saw the link but it use a webservice too and note a simple database connection :(

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) connect directly to a database from a mobile phone/tablet. Besides exhausting available connections and the security implications which are HUGE... This is physically problematic as the JDBC drivers are often native and can't be physically ported to devices.

Comment: ok Thanks all
@ShaiAlmog i see the link https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html

thanks for your responses ;)